# How do I add FrameLayout and ImageViews within it Programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

There are plenty of similar questions asked in SO, but then also, please take time to read my question.

I need to create a UI programmatically that would have multiple `ImageView`, all positioned at different location of the screen and having their associated click events (its a game app). I found that `FrameLayout` is appropriate choice, where I can set margins on my own and have it positioned at desired location.

Now, I'm confused whether to have `FrameLayout` for every single `ImageView` I create, or to keep single FrameLayout and add all ImageViews within it, but set each imageview **at different position**.

In either of the case, how can I add FrameLayout, and ImageView within it, programmatically and also set its margin such that it can be placed anywhere on the screen.

Note that my main canvas, which will carry all these ImageViews has background, and the canvas is a `LinearLayout` set via XML, so my `onCreate()` already has `setContentView(R.layout.game_canvas);`, and I'd be using `addContentView()` to add additional views, but this method too accepts `LayoutParams` object as it second parameter, so what exactly should I set for this, when I add my FrameLayouts using this method?

My question might be confusing itself, so please let me know if I need to elaborate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FrameLayouts are designed to only hold one View, so this isn't really the appropriate choice.

Use a RelativeLayout to hold all of your ImageViews. You can position each ImageView by setting the margins in their LayoutParams.

E.g. The following code would place an ImageView at coordinates 50,50:

```
RelativeLayout imgLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.an_image);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.setMargins(50, 50, 0, 0);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

imgLayout.addView(iv, lp);
```

You can then add this RelativeLayout to your main LinearLayout using its addView() method.

Comment: Will `RelativeLayout` allow its child `ImageView`s to overlap each other for a few pixels (think of the playing cards, stacked as in hand)?

Comment: Yes, they do. The order is determined by the order you add them.

Comment: @nmw how to add a fragment using this code. Like you are loading a picture, can I replace a fragment in this code?